# Is a script that creates an number, searches database for the number, and repeat until it finds a unique number a bad script to use?

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, unique

Ok, so I've written a script that will create a random number, check the database and if number exists in a userid row, it will recreate a new number and continue until it finds an available number...I started thinking though, if my site gets HUGE, wouldn't that be a terrible thing it trying to randomly find numbers and possibly having to continuously repeat itself...is there a better way of doing this or is this the route to go?

The user ID is not a private number as it can be used to get to user profiles...its being setup like Facebook where the long string of numbers OR a username can go to the persons profile.

Comment: What's wrong with something like `AUTOINCREMENT` or a GUID?

Comment: so you are the first one ever to create a unique id for a db row?

Comment: I'm using it for user id's, and someone mentioned that using AI might not be the best way to go for user id's if the number is a public number.

Comment: depends entirely how you use it.

Comment: basically a member signs up, and they get a unique user id..I just don't want to start having troubles with it if I get a lot of sign ups. Trying to do everything the best way possible the first time around.

Comment: so you have a lot of people and a lot of ids, what's the problem with AUTOINCREMENT ?

Comment: read my above comment. Someone mentioned to me it would be better to have random user id's that are public than auto increment numbers. Several people agree'd with them, so I went with that concept.

Comment: If the ID needs to be "secret", uou could generate it from the user's auto-incremented ID and a random salt. This is assuming the ID can have letters in it, though (as using a "number salt" could lead to duplicates). If the IDs should be public, however, AI is usually a good way to go.

Comment: someone told me "the .. did .. when you .." Understand the issues, don't believer anything you read on the internet.

Comment: the ID is not secret though, it will be public as people can get to their profile using it. It's just like Facebook where you have both a long user id # sequence AND a username.  So for something like this, I should use a AI # for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are (for whatever reason) trying to stop someone from visiting a page like

`profile/<user_id>`, and seeing that `user_id` = 100, then trying `profile/101`, `profile/102`, etc, etc.

If that is the case, then you can use something like this (along with autoincrementing ids)

```
class Crypt {

    public static function encrypt($data) {

        $config = LoadSomeConfig();

        // open the module to be used.  There are several listed at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php     
        $mod = mcrypt_module_open($config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '');

        // use config set initialization vector.  We will use a constant here as we do not want to include this for decryption
        if (isset($config->vector)) {
            $iv = $config->vector;
        } else {
            die("NO IV SET!");
        }

        $key_size = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($mod);
        $key = substr($config->key, 0, $key_size);
        mcrypt_generic_init($mod, $key, $iv);

        // Do the encryption using the cipher module defined
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($mod, $data);

        // cleanup
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($mod);
        mcrypt_module_close($mod);

        // Changed the output based on the config encoding value.  Currently supported values, base64 and hex.
        switch ($config->encoding) {
            case "base64":
                $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted);
                break;
            case "hex":
                $encrypted = bin2hex($encrypted);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return $encrypted;
    }

    public static function decrypt($data){

        if (empty($data)) {
            return '';
        }

        // config options set include the cipher, mode and secret key
        $config = LoadSomeConfig(); 

        // Change encrypted data base to binary based on the encoding mechanism used to generate the data
        switch ($config->encoding) {
            case "base64":
                $data = base64_decode($data);
                break;
            case "hex":
                $data = pack("H*", $data);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        if (isset($config->vector)) {
            $iv = $config->vector;
        } else {
            die("NO IV SET!");
        }

        $mod = mcrypt_module_open($config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '');
        $key_size = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($mod);
        // max key size is 448 bits
        $key = substr($config->key, 0, $key_size);
        mcrypt_generic_init($mod, $key, $iv);

        // decrypt the data
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($mod, $data);

        // cleanup
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($mod);
        mcrypt_module_close($mod);

        return trim($decrypted);
    }
}
```

You would then have a route like `profile/c2ffd340ea3b71ca065e6add4143f36d`

In your profile page, assuming the user_id was accessible in `user_id`, you could simple do:

```
$user_id = Crypt::decrypt($user_id);
```

And proceed like normal.  When creating a link to someone's profile page you would use something like `profile/<?php echo Crypt::encrypt($user->user_id); ?>`

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is exactly what I was looking for in an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your user names are unique (I guess) maybe it would be better to just let the /profile/ controller grab the user name from the URL and load the profile.

The other way you are not only adding obfuscation stuff to our code - What, if your encryption code changes for some reason? All external links, bookmarks and so on will not work anymore. And you will have better search engine coverage, because user names in the URL are much more worth than some cryptic stuff. Ah yes, and you won't have the *theoretically* possible collisions of whatever algorithm you choose, when you decide to hash;)